# nginx, append /life/ to every request to www.a.com

Tags: nginx

I want to append a string to every request that refers to the root.

eg) www.a.com -> www.a.com/life/

I wrote the conf as below, but the brower said there are cyclic redirections:

```
            if ($host ~ 'www.a.com$') {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.a.com/life/ permanent;
            }
```

How to write this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this

```
 if ($host ~ 'www.a.com$') {
                    rewrite ^/$ http://www.a.com/life/ permanent;
            }
```

Comment: I think `location = / {}` is better.